# Can't resize image in Rich Text field since 2.5 update

Tags: image, image-transforms, richtext

after upgrade to 2.5, it seems it's not possible to click on the inserted image and resize it in the Rich Text Field. If you click it now, you directly get a popup to give in the Title, link or select the alignment.
It used to show an 'Edit' overlay & the option to resize it with the mouse.

Any others experiencing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest downgrading to Redactor I, which always worked fine for me. Pixel & Tonic made a plugin, so it's fairly easy to do and so far I can't find any issues.

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI

Comment: Didn't see that, thx! Will use this from now on. Hopefully in the future Redactor II is getting these functionalities back. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It's not Craft that's broken it, but the new version of Redactor that's "superior in every way" acording to them:
https://imperavi.com/blog/redactor-superior-in-every-way/

Comment: Not that superior anymore then... That was one of the things my Clients loved in Craft :)

Answer (score 1):

The imageResizable and imageEditable settings were apparently deprecated in Redactor 2.

https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/upgrading-to-redactor-ii/

Comment: No workaround, plugin available that you know off? Seems a stupid decision to me, especially to my clients.

Comment: The best I've come up with is to enable the source button in the config, and use inline styles to resize the image. 

https://craftcms.com/help/redactor-ii-configs

To make matters worse, once you've made the changes to the html, it's difficult to keep Redactor from stripping the code out (click the "HTML" button on the toolbar, add the inline styles, click the HTML button again, then hit save. If you save from the source view, it removes your code). On top of that, if you make any edits through the wysiwyg after you've added the code, it'll remove the code again.

Comment: maybe better to add another image field then and define some image transforms and alignment.

Comment: Not sure that would work for me. Need the ability to place images at specific places w/ the text, which I don't think is possible without using an equally messy/limited approach. I just can't for the life of me understand why this feature was removed from redactor.

Comment: Dumb update!!!!