# Extra spaces appearing in Rich Text fields after 2.5 update

Tags: redactor, richtext

In addition to the inability to resize images in the rich text fields ([mentioned elsewhere](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12634/cant-resize-image-in-rich-text-field-since-2-5-update)), I'm having issues with rich text fields, particularly in Matrix blocks, inserting extra spaces between paragraphs.

While an entry may be rendering normal on the frontend, opening up the entry will show the paragraphs with large spaces between them. Looking into the HTML, these appear as a series of tags like

```
<br><p><br></p>
```

Strangely, when switching back and forth between the normal and HTML view, more and more of these spaces are inserted between the paragraphs. Do I have the option to rollback to the earlier version of Redactor? Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: This is happening for me too. I downgraded back to 2.4 and a db backup to solve the problem. I can confirm that on 2.4 and Redactor I this extra tag issue doesn't happen and is semantically correct (i.e. a single </p> closes out a paragraph with no extra tags being inserted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is in!

[Running Redactor “I” in Craft 2.5](https://craftcms.com/news/running-redactor-i-in-craft-2-5)

Just used this on one of my problem upgrades and it worked seamlessly - now they get to be in on the 2.5 party too :)

Comment: Thanks Alan - rolling back to earlier version not a massive fix, long-term. Anyone know the cause behind this occurring in Redactor II?

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Alan! I see where Imperavi is coming from, but this was a rough switch to make midstream. Thankfully, this plugin totally saves the day!