# Image and italics issues in Rich Text editor since 2.5 update

Tags: redactor, image, richtext

In addition to the [lack of image resizing](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12634/cant-resize-image-in-rich-text-field-since-2-5-update) and the [odd extra spacing](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12647/extra-spaces-appearing-in-rich-text-fields-after-2-5-update), the latest Redactor implementation also lacks support for aligning images left or right.

I've also discovered any text that was previously italicized by the previous text editor disappears when rendered in the new one. If the entry is saved with the new text editor in place, all previously italicized copy disappears.

Until this implementation is remedied, I've plugged the earlier version of Redactor into this instance to stem client complaints. Doing so completely disables image placement and Live Preview, but it beats the alternative.

Is this the correct route of action in order to restore this functionality, or is there a better way? Please advise.

Comment: Hi Marcus, there doesn't seem to be an actual "question" here. I'm going to close this as "unclear what you're asking"... if you think there's actually a question in there, feel free to make edits.

Comment: Edited in a more question-like form. I'm certainly looking for answers.

Comment: Curious to know this as well. Users are upset over the lack of image resizing now with redactor II.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way! Pixel & Tonic has addressed this with the Redactor I plugin, available here: https://craftcms.com/news/running-redactor-i-in-craft-2-5

This completely restores the previous content rendering and functionality (including image sizing/alignment and Live Preview).

I understand where Imperavi is coming from, championing for cleaner data, but it just wasn't part of this project's workflow. When I start my next project fresh, I'll be using Redactor II.